# How to autoextend maximo contract at due date?

Tags: customization, cron-task, maximo, contract

I'm trying to know whether there is a standard way to auto extend a Maximo contract at due date. In most Maximo contract application, there are fields to set up auto extend but there is not any cron task to handle such purpose. Do I really have to create a custom cron task and script for such purpose? Share with me you experience.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider implementing an appropriate Escalation which could check for appropriate contracts with a due date occurring within a defined time period based on the current date (e.g. due date occurs within the next 5 days -> duedate between getdate() and getdate() + 5)

Typically we have used this type of logic in conjunction with a communication template to send an email to the appropriate party who then manually reviews and updates the appropriate contract. But you could add an appropriate action to the escalation to increment the due date by an appropriate amount + also send out the associated email to notify the appropriate parties of the implemented update?

Escalations are coded within the Escalations application, the actions application (target actions) and the communications template application (email template)

:)